# .NET GC Accessing a synchronised object from a finalizer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, garbage-collection

I recently read this article [Safe Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188793.aspx) as I was curious about the thread safety of calls made from a finaliser. I wrote the following code to test access to a static thread safe collection from a finaliser.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GCThreadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static class FinaliserCollection
        {
            private static Queue<int> s_ItemQueue = new Queue<int>();
            private static System.Object s_Lock = new System.Object();

            public static void AddItem(int itemValue)
            {
                lock(s_Lock)
                {
                    s_ItemQueue.Enqueue(itemValue);
                }
            }

            public static bool TryGetItem(out int item)
            {
                lock(s_Lock)
                {
                    if (s_ItemQueue.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        item = -1;
                        return false;
                    }

                    item = s_ItemQueue.Dequeue();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        class FinaliserObject
        {
            private int m_ItemValue;

            public FinaliserObject(int itemValue)
            {
                m_ItemValue = itemValue;
            }

            ~FinaliserObject()
            {
                FinaliserCollection.AddItem(m_ItemValue);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int itemValueIn = 0;
            int itemValueOut = 0;

            while (itemValueOut < 10000)
            {
                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
                    (delegate(object value)
                    {
                        new FinaliserObject((int)value);

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);

                    }, itemValueIn);

                itemValueIn = itemValueIn + 1;

                // This seems to stop finaliser from
                // being called?
                // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);

                int tempItemValueOut = -1;
                if (FinaliserCollection.TryGetItem(out tempItemValueOut))
                    itemValueOut = tempItemValueOut;
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("Finished after {0} items created", itemValueOut);
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Without the 'Sleep' call in the while loop this code seems to run fine but is it really safe from deadlocking? Would it ever be possible for a finaliser call to be made while a queued thread pool item is accessing the static collection? Why does adding the 'Sleep' to the main threads while loop appear to stop all finalisers from being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow.  What the... This is the most bizarre piece of code I've ever seen.  @.@

First of all, what finalizer call are you referring to?  The only finalizer I see is the finalizer for the `FinaliserObject`, which will be called 10,000 times, and can be called independently of whatever's going on on the static collection.  I.E. yes, those objects can be destroyed while other objects are being dequeued from the collection.  This isn't an issue.

The static collection itself won't be cleaned up until the app itself exits.

Keep in mind that there's *absolutely* no guarantee when or if those finalizers will be called before the app itself exits.  Your static collection could be completely empty when you exit.

Worse, you're assigning `itemValueOut` to whatever the last value you pull out of the queue is... which is NOT the number of items created, as you imply in your WriteLine().  Because those destructors are called in any possible order, you could theoretically add to the queue 10,000, 9,999, 9,998, ... 2, 1, in that order.

Which is further an issue, because you're removing from the queue 10,000 times, but on the last loop, it's very possible there won't be an object to dequeue, in which case you're guaranteed to get -1 for the number of items returned (even if the other 9,999 items worked successfully).

To answer your question, this code cannot deadlock.  A deadlock would happen if `AddItem()` called `TryGetItem()`, but those locks are pretty much guaranteed to keep each other out of the static collection while adding or removing items.

Where you're tempting fate is that you can exit your app without all of the `FinaliserObject`s having added themselves to the queue.  Meaning one of the finalizers could fire and try to add to the `FinaliserCollection`, but the `FinaliserCollection` has already been disposed.  What you're doing in the finaliser is **terrible**.

But yes, a finalizer call can happen while you're calling `FinaliserCollection.TryGetItem()`.  The finalizer will block and wait until `TryGetItem()` emerges from the `lock()`, at which point it will add another item.  This is not an issue.

As for the `sleep()` command, you're probably just throwing the timing of the garbage collection off.  Remember, your objects won't be collected/finalized until the GC decides it needs the resources.

Sorry for being so emphatic... I know you're just trying to test a concept but I really don't understand why you would want to do what you're trying to do in the finalizer.  If there's really a legitimate goal here, doing it in the finalizer is *not* the correct answer.

**Edit** 

From what I'm reading and what Sasha is saying, no you will not have a deadlock.  The finalizer thread may be blocked waiting for the lock, but the GC will not wait for the finalizer, and will thus unsuspend the threads, allowing the locks to be released.

In any case, this is a very strong argument for why you shouldn't be making calls like this in a finalizer... the finalizer is *only* for releasing unmanaged resources.  Anything else is playing roulette.

Comment: +1 for this: I know you're just trying to test a concept but I really don't understand why you would want to do what you're trying to do in the finalizer. If there's really a legitimate goal here, doing it in the finalizer is not the correct answer.

Comment: This is part of a investigation to a problem we have with a .NET object holding a pointer to a reference counted C++ object which may result in the finaliser destroying the C++ object. Problem is that this may be from a random thread and the operations performed may be difficult to make thread-safe. I'm not however suggesting this is the solution, I was just curious as to the specifics of this case.

Comment: The third last paragraph in the response is getting to the heart of the question. This is where I require clarification. From what I understand of the article and MSDN documentation is that the GC suspends other working threads (when they hit a safe point) while garbage collection is performed. Does that not include the execution of the finalizers?

Comment: @karmasponge: No, because finalizers do not run during GC. A special finalizer thread runs finalizers, and it runs them after the relevant GC cycle has completed. (Furthermore, some parts of GC can run concurrently with the application's threads; see "workstation GC".)

Comment: @Sasha:  To clarify, the GC calls the finalizer of an object before it garbage-collects that object (the finalizer executing on a special thread, as you pointed out)

Comment: @karmasponge:  What that means is that your finalizers will execute *as part of the garbage collection*.  And I'm getting now exactly what you're after... the finalizer calls a method that requests a lock... if that lock is being held by another thread, and that thread is suspended, I believe you may indeed have a deadlock.  Let me modify my answer

Comment: I think the example you've posted is very different than the example listed in your comment... can you post code that is closer to what you're after?  The finalizer should be able to release a C++ object without issue, regardless of what thread it's on, but maybe I'm still not understanding something.

Comment: Also note that a proper implementation of IDisposable is preferred to relying on a finalizer.  Because a finalizer is never guaranteed to be called, it's only a fallback.  Read here for more info:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=VS.100%29.aspx (details on finalizers) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx (how to implement IDisposable)

Comment: @James: I don't think it's accurate to say that. The GC enqueues a reference to the object to the f-reachable queue, and wakes up the finalizer thread (using an event). The finalizer thread dequeues the reference from the queue, and runs the object's finalizer. The GC does not wait for finalization to complete -- only on the next GC cycle the object's memory will be reclaimed. (Promotion between generations notwithstanding.)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense... in that case the answer is that there would not be a deadlock, because the locking threads would be unsuspended.  I'm assuming then that the GC simply promotes those objects to a higher generation, rather than collecting them